# Email Fluid 3 column design WITHOUT media queries

Tags: html, email, fluid-layout

Ok so after hours of patching together a fluid/media query responsive email I find out that most email clients strip out any elements within a `<style></style>`. meaning anything not in-line wont work including all media queries. Massive head ache!

So is there a way of making a 3 column email with an outer container of 610px and all styling to be in-line that will simply scale down so you can view it on mobile?

I can get it to work for single col but when it comes to 2 or 3 I'm coming unstuck.

Comment: You want 3 columns next to each other on mobile, right?

Comment: Yes. I would like them all to scale down when the device gets smaller than 610px but not get any bigger than max of 610px on larger screens.

Comment: I found this article on [Creating a centered, responsive design without media queries](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/4240/creating-a-centred-responsive-design-without-media-queries?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Creating+a+Gmail-friendly+responsive+design&utm_content=Creating+a+Gmail-friendly+responsive+design+Version+A+CID_de3f91eee3e5f4c43d24c5be2b4b0ff4&utm_source=Email%20marketing%20software&utm_term=Get%20the%20upper%20hand%20over%20Gmail) but it still requires a media querie! I have tried it without this bit and it stops the email scaling. :(

Comment: If ANYTHING NOT INLINE doesn't work on a majority of clients does that mean that responsive email designs are pretty pointless in most email clients? Is there no way to make a fluid email design work by using inline styles only?

Comment: 3 columns. On a potentially 2.5-inch wide screen? Your columns are going to be less than an inch wide, and it's **physical** size that matters, not **px** size.